# Need a simulator tool to test Protocols of SS7/INAP

Tags: linux, simulation, protocol

Good day.. I am looking for a tool where i can test protocols like SS7/INAP & ENUM

The tool will be used to test a call flow between users... As far as i have checked, i had a little options to go with ( Eg: Seagull )

When i try install the packages of Linux Seagull which was provided by them i encountered the below error

```
# rpm -ivh seagull-octcap-protocol-1.8.2-linux-2.6-intel.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        libTTL.so.1()(64bit) is needed by seagull-octcap-protocol-1.8.2-0.i386
        libTTLBase.so.1()(64bit) is needed by seagull-octcap-protocol-1.8.2-0.i386
        libntl.so.1()(64bit) is needed by seagull-octcap-protocol-1.8.2-0.i386

# rpm -ivh seagull-trans-tls-1.8.2-linux-2.6-intel.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        libcrypto.so.0.9.8()(64bit) is needed by seagull-trans-tls-1.8.2-0.i386
        libssl.so.0.9.8()(64bit) is needed by seagull-trans-tls-1.8.2-0.i386


# rpm -ivh seagull-trans-sctp-1.8.2-linux-2.6-intel.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        libsctplib.so.1()(64bit) is needed by seagull-trans-sctp-1.8.2-0.i386
        libsctpsocket.so.2()(64bit) is needed by seagull-trans-sctp-1.8.2-0.i386

# rpm -ivh seagull-crypto-1.8.2-linux-2.6-intel.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        libcrypto.so.0.9.8()(64bit) is needed by seagull-crypto-1.8.2-0.i386
        libssl.so.0.9.8()(64bit) is needed by seagull-crypto-1.8.2-0.i386
```

The below are the packages provided by them

```
seagull-synchro-protocol-1.8.2-linux-2.6-intel.rpm
seagull-radius-protocol-1.8.2-linux-2.6-intel.rpm
seagull-octcap-protocol-1.8.2-linux-2.6-intel.rpm
seagull-diameter-protocol-1.8.2-linux-2.6-intel.rpm
seagull-core-1.8.2-linux-2.6-intel.rpm
seagull-xcap-protocol-1.8.2-linux-2.6-intel.rpm
seagull-trans-tls-1.8.2-linux-2.6-intel.rpm
seagull-trans-sctp-1.8.2-linux-2.6-intel.rpm
seagull-sip-protocol-1.8.2-linux-2.6-intel.rpm
seagull-msrp-protocol-1.8.2-linux-2.6-intel.rpm
seagull-library-java-synchro-1.8.2-linux-2.6-intel.rpm
seagull-h248-protocol-1.8.2-linux-2.6-intel.rpm
seagull-crypto-1.8.2-linux-2.6-intel.rpm
seagull-external-lib-sctp-1.8.2-linux-2.6-intel.rpm
```

It would be really helpful, if i am helped here...

I need 2 things.

i.) Any simulator which can be used to test these protocols. ( open source is preferred )

ii.) How to fix these dependencies issues ?? Any one can provide the location for these RPM files to install the packages..??

Thanks for your response and great help in advance...!

Best Regards, Sukumar MS Software Engineer

Answer (score -1):

What exactly do you require? Check if these relate to what you are asking:

- https://github.com/akibsayyed/safeseven
- https://github.com/ernw/ss7MAPer

-Kushagra